# Why report is not getting added to my report viewer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, rdlc

I am trying to add RDLC report to report viewer but it throws error

[image]

I tried every thing but it doesn't work. I suddenly stopped working. I am currently using Vs 2013 but tried other version too and same error everywhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why RDLC report is not getting added to report viewer ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390714/why-rdlc-report-is-not-getting-added-to-report-viewer)

Comment: yeah but neither that was answered not this