# Why RDLC report is not getting added to report viewer ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, rdlc

I am using vs 2013 but my project suddenly stopped creating RDLC reports. It was working fine but not working now. I tried other projects which just works fine but not this one. It throws error while adding report to report viewer or creating by report wizard.

[image]

Comment: Try to clean Debug and Release folders in your solution. App_Code folder is your own code folder and you might missing add reference of one or two dll used in code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why report is not getting added to my report viewer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384227/why-report-is-not-getting-added-to-my-report-viewer)